# auto-ident in code mode

Tags: feature-request

Pretty self explanatory. If I write code straight into SO, seems reasonable the next line will start at the indentation of the previous one (the most basic implementation). Pressing space bar at least 4 times every time is excruciatingly annoying.

Comment: The editor already supports that; just use ctrl-enter / cmd-enter.

Comment: That doesn't work for me in Safari, @Martijn. Cmd+Enter does nothing; Ctrl+Enter immediately submits the edit.

Comment: @CodyGray That's an actual duplicate, I didn't ask about tab. Bummer this isn't going to happen then.

Comment: Ick, mis-remembered, it's shift-enter (I have a userscript that adds tab support, so it's been a while).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the tip. Should be written somewhere when posting.

Comment: I used to have a bunch of nice user scripts. Then the Google folks who maintain Chrome decided that I was too stupid to be trusted with user scripts and disabled them. Shift+Enter works, though! (Although it is a bit laggy…)